# add pyqtgraph plot to QTDesigner with pyside2

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2, pyqtgraph

I have a QTDesigner file with a QVBoxLayout where I try to add a GLViewWidget:

I used this [Embed Pyqtgraph to PySide2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536194/embed-pyqtgraph-to-pyside2) example to create my code.
In my application all this is embedded in an ROS enviroment. 
The QTDesigner QVBoxLayout:

```
...
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>10</width>
             <height>10</height>
...
```

I try to add the GLViewWidget to the QVBoxLayout via the addWidget function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

# ROS imports
import rospkg
import rospy

# QT imports
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QObject
import pyqtgraph.opengl as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore
import ros_numpy

class ConfigUi(QObject):

    def __init__(self, subscriber, parent=None):
        super(ConfigUi, self).__init__(parent)
        r = rospkg.RosPack()

        pkg_path = r.get_path('config_ui')
        ui_file = QFile(pkg_path + '/ui/main_window.ui')
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader = QUiLoader()

        self.subscriber = subscriber

        self.window = loader.load(ui_file)
        self.gv = self.window.verticalLayout_2
        self.w = self.plotWidget()
        self.gv.addWidget(self.w)
        self.w.show()

    def plotWidget(self):
        w = pg.GLViewWidget()
        w.opts['distance'] = 20
        w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: GLScatterPlotItem')

        self.sp3 = pg.GLScatterPlotItem(pos=ros_numpy.point_cloud2.pointcloud2_to_xyz_array(self.subscriber.pc),
                                        color=(1, 1, 1, .3), size=0.01, pxMode=False)
        w.addItem(self.sp3)
        t = QtCore.QTimer()
        t.timeout.connect(self.update)
        t.start(50)
        return w

    def update(self):
        pc = ros_numpy.point_cloud2.pointcloud2_to_xyz_array(self.subscriber.pc)
        self.sp3.setData(pos=pc)
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    listener = CameraListner()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ConfigUi(subscriber)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After start I get the Error:

```
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(GLViewWidget)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget, int = 0, PySide2.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = 0)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of PySide2, pyqtgraph and python are you using? Try using the latest versions of PySide2 and pyqtgraph.

Comment: hey, I use pygraph verision 0.11.0.dev0+gdb483f8

Comment: Hey, Did you find any solution for your problem, I am struggling with same problem. If you get any solution please reply me..

Answer (score 0):

I am new to using pyqtgraph byt successfully plot a list of values in a bargraph by first placing a QWidget with the object name 'plotwidget' in Qt Designer. This Qwidget is then promoted to the pyqtgraph.PlotWidget class. The code to plot my bars is then simply:

```
bg = pg.BarGraphItem(x=range(len(value_list)), height=value_list, width=0.8, brush='b')
self.ui.plotwidget.addItem(bg)
```

I would try to promote a QWidget to a GLViewWidget in Qt Designer and then add a GLScatterPlotItem just like I do with the BarGraphItem in my code.

I use pyqtpgraph 0.11.0rc0 and Pyside2 5.13.1